# Passing user data after Login in JavaFX

Tags: java, authentication, javafx, controller

I'm trying to pass user's data, after login, to his home page (to set labels with his name and so on).
I've already tried a few things but none of them worked for me.
My intention is to:

1. login a user with a database connection (no problems there)
2. retrieve his data from database (no problems there)
3. pass his data to the home page controller (right after login)

In particular I want to set a Label with his name and an Image for his profile, all of this data is stored in the database and retrieved at login.
I've tried to set the controller with scene builder but in this way I don't know how to pass parameters to his constructor. So I removed the fx:controller attribute from the fxml file and set the controller this way:

```
//Inizilized the user at login
User_Home_Controller userHomeController = new User_Home_Controller(loggedUser);
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/UserHomePage.fxml"));
loader.setController(userHomeController);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

But it gives me a NullPointerException on the UserHomeController constructor.
All of this happens inside the LoginController. Is this the problem?
The code I'm posting is another solution. I'm using a method of the user home controller to set the user and the data for the label. This solution also gives me a NullPointerException at the method initData.
This is my User_Home_Controller:

```
package controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import entity.VolunteerUser;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class User_Home_Controller implements Initializable{

    VolunteerUser currentUser;

    public void initData(VolunteerUser user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        this.nomeCognome.setText(user.getNome() + " "+ user.getCognome());
    }


    @FXML
    private Text nomeCognome;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

}
```

This is the LoginController:

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


import entity.Login;
import entity.VolunteerUser;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login_Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;

    @FXML
    private TextField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private Button registerButton;


    @FXML
    void loginPressed(ActionEvent event) {

        //All of the login stuff is missing here, but it's okay

        int loginResult = login.logger(usernameField.getText(), passwordField.getText());
        if (loginResult>0) {


            if (login.getTableUser() == 1) {


                VolunteerUser loggedUser = vrep.getVolunteerByID(login.returnID(usernameField.getText(), 1));
                System.out.println(loggedUser.getCognome()); //This works

                try {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/UserHomePage.fxml"));
                    Parent root = loader.load();

                    User_Home_Controller userHomeController = loader.<User_Home_Controller>getController();
                    userHomeController.initData(loggedUser);

                    Stage home = (Stage) loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
                    home.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
                    home.show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


}
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.keyReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:161)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4058)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:4004)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2121)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2595)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.User_Home_Controller.initData(User_Home_Controller.java:121)
    at controllers.Login_Controller.loginPressed(Login_Controller.java:68)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: If `user` is non null, the only other possibility for this code to throw a NPE with this stacktrace is `nomeCognome` being null. Why is that the case? No idea, probably the fxml does not contain an element with the appropriate `fx:id`, but you haven't posted info about the fxml.

Comment: please post a minimal source or **/view/UserHomePage.fxml**, this type of error occurs when the `fx:controller` value is not set in the the FXML file

Comment: Resolved. The error was that nomeCognome was not specified as fx:id of the label of the scene builder...Sorry. Thank you